# WinJS.Binding multiple sources

Tags: javascript, data-binding, windows-8, winjs

I'm new to data binding, but it looked like an easy way to achieve what I need to do.

My problem (as you can see) is that I have two (or more) of these boxes with different data on each page. The code works fine, but it **displays the same thing in both divs**.

Here's my sample code:

*Javascript:*

```
var people = {
   name: "Jeff",
   age: 37,
   location: "New Jersey"
}

var animals = {
   name: "Kiki",
   age: 2,
   location: "Canada"
}

var elementPeople = document.getElementById("peopleBox");
var bindingSrcPeople = WinJS.Binding.as(people);

var elementAnimals = document.getElementById("animalBox");
var bindingSrcAnimals = WinJS.Binding.as(animals);

.
.
.

WinJS.Binding.processAll(elementPeople, bindingSrcPeople);
WinJS.Binding.processAll(elementAnimals, bindingSrcAnimals);
```

*HTML:*

```
<div id="peopleBox">
  <div class="" data-win-bind="textContent:name"></div>
  <div class="" data-win-bind="textContent:location"></div>
</div>


<div id="animalBox">
  <div class="" data-win-bind="textContent:name"></div>
  <div class="" data-win-bind="textContent:location"></div>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: I tried the code. This code displays fine different data for two divs. may be code in your app is different.